# joomla 2.5! JPagination, Unsure about how to retrieve the value from getLimitBox $option

Tags: php, joomla, pagination, joomla2.5

So I've been following this tutorial on [JPagination](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_JPagination_in_your_component#orderUpIcon.28.29) and on the section about **with JDatabase** it has a variable `$option` on line 2 `"$option.limit"`. (It hasn't been referenced anywhere else on the page, I'm unsure on where this value is being declared/initialized).

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$lim    = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.limit", 'limit', 14, 'int'); //I guess getUserStateFromRequest is for session or different reasons
$lim0   = JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int');
$db->setQuery('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS x, y, z FROM jos_content WHERE x',$lim0, $lim);
$rL=&$db->loadAssocList();
if (empty($rL)) {$jAp->enqueueMessage($db->getErrorMsg(),'error'); return;} 
else {
////Here the beauty starts
$db->setQuery('SELECT FOUND_ROWS();');  //no reloading the query! Just asking for total without limit
jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
$pageNav = new JPagination( $db->loadResult(), $lim0, $lim );
foreach($rL as $r) {
//your display code here
}
echo $pageNav->getListFooter(  ); //Displays a nice footer
```

I've had a look around joomla docs on pages such as [this](http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JPagination/getLimitBox) to see if the `$option` variable is relevant to the `limitBox`, because the `limitbox` [image: displaybox] is what is setting the amount things to be displayed. But I haven't had much luck.

Therefore I'm wondering how are you meant to obtain the information from the variable `$option` and/or the current selection from the `LimitBox` in JPagination.

Pastebin link to my [implementation](http://pastebin.com/2pG0Zz2x) [expires in 24 hours]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article is out of date in a few ways, it was originally written for J1.5 and assumes a lot of knowledge about the inner workings. I wouldn't recommend it for J2.5.

Pagination is mostly automatic today if you're following the J2.5 MVC and using it's built-in (for the most) part user state mechanism. To start with, in J2.5 your model should should be extending `JModelList` if you're displaying a list of content items. `JModelList` extends `JModel` by adding useful features for dealing with lists.

One of these features is the `populateState()` method, in it's base state it will look after your list limits for you if you're using a `<select>` named `limit`. It does this by managing the base userState for you, I would recommend reading through `/administrator/com_contact` and `/libraries/joomla/application/component/modellist.php` ([Joomla API JModelList](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Application/JModelList.html)).

`populateState()` is used to help the model keep track of basics for your component in a semi-automatic way. In addition to list limits, it will also track the search field and the sort column & it's direction. If you extension needs to track other user states or override settings you can create a `populateState()` in your model file - just remember to call the parent before hand so you still get the built-in benefits. e.g.

```
protected function populateState()
{
    parent::populateState();
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

    /* Do some groovy stuff here
     * like adding our own form variables to the state to use later
     */
    $srid = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.project.srid','srid');
    $this->setState('project.srid', $srid);

}
```

For user state you can [read more in this article (which also covers Pagination briefly) "How to use user state variables"](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables)

Comment: Before I mark this as answered, I have a few questions on my mind.. such as how is `populateState` used? with the view and model? Regards

Comment: See my expanded answer, the best way to get a handle on it is to read the code and the article I suggested and then experiment with your code.